# Does life have a distinct entropic signiture detectable as a distinct thermal radiation signature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, thermal-radiation, dissipation

Suppose you have two closed systems containing the same elements in the same amounts. Their only interaction with the rest of the universe is that by the absorption and radiation electromagnetic waves. The energy input to the two systems is the same, either because they are both subject to the same radiation and have a perfectly absorptive shell, or because the incident radiation is adjusted to compensate for any differences in reflection. The systems are sufficiently distant that they are effectively point-sources. All we observe is the intensity and frequency distribution of the radiation absorbed, and the intensity and frequency distribution of the radiation emitted.  The only difference between the two systems is this: One contains life.

Assume this life is in steady state, neither growing nor diminishing in physical or energetic terms, with replication precisely offsetting loss to death and decay.  You may assume that non-living dissipative systems, in the Prigogine sense, are either not present or are present to the same degree.

Given these assumptions, can the presence of life be deduced from differences in the intensity and frequency of the emitted radiation alone? Or to put it differently, does life have a distinctive thermodynamic signature that is distinct from any specific signature in chemical equilibrium?

If so, how would you characterize the radiative difference between the living and the dead?

Comment: Possibly relevant: ["The potential for detecting ‘life as we don’t
know it’ by fractal complexity analysis"](https://repositorio.uc.cl/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11534/12897/1115.pdf).

Comment: I am pretty sure that the system containing life must have an entropic signature. Somehow the "albedo" of it must be lower as life seems to require energy even if steady state.

Comment: I think that the problem with the question is how you prepare the systems. When you write about input and/ or adjustment. It is hard to follow but it could also mean that everything is tailored to mask the signature you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not certain if there’s an electromagnetic signature to humans.

However, anything that always follows a spacetime geodesic is not alive. Birds are alive, trees are alive (like giant straws), and astronauts are alive. Flying lava is not alive (it follows a parabolic path). Light is not alive.

Comment: Life (not just human life) becomes more orderly by making its environment less orderly -- by absorbing Gibbs free energy from the environment. That is what I am hoping creates a distinctive signiture. And I am pretty sure this is powered by the temperature gradient between the center of the sun and intersteller space. That is the river that turns this water wheel.